# How to send new params before resolving a route in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have this route that has a `value` param

```
  routes.push({
    name: 'test',
    path: '/test/:value',
    component: resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages/test.vue'),
  });
```

I would like to update the route so that it actually sends `value` and `test` as params

```
  routes.push({
    name: 'test',
    path: '/test/:value',
    component: resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages/test.vue'),
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
      to.params.test = 'test';

      next({ params: to.params });
    },
  });
```

Then I can catch it in a vue page

```
async fetch({ store, route }) {
  console.log(route.params.value);
  console.log(route.params.test);
},
```

The `beforeEnter` code I created above is not working.. new `test` param is not being sent.

Any ideas?

Comment: `test` isn't a parameter in your route

Comment: shouldn't it be `path: '/:test/:value',` in your example code; instead of `path: '/test/:value',`

Comment: I know. I want to add it. Don't want to change the route path

Comment: So then add it to your params in your component, but not your route defintion

Comment: Hey, I'm not a vue coder, but have you look around middleware implementation ? https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/implementing-a-simple-middleware-with-vue-router/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `next` takes a params object as argument

`next(to.params)`

Works but I can't find it in the docs

edit [Working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEZjNP?editors=1012)

Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere? Try to log the params as in the example codepen

Comment: I got it to work.. not sure how.. i just rewrite all my logic. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a path/name as well to next, like so:

```
  routes.push({
    name: 'test',
    path: '/test/:value',
    component: resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages/test.vue'),
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
      next({ name: 'test', params: { test: 'test' });
    },
  });
```

Comment: I try giving it the `path or name` but doesn't work

Comment: does it also happen with params you have declared in your path?